# Kotlin - "Required: Nothing, Found: Any"

Tags: kotlin

```
fun MutableList<out Any>.reorder(a: Int, b: Int){
    val first = this[a]
    val second = this[b]
    removeAt(a)
    add(a, second)
    removeAt(b)
    add(b, first)
}
```

The add functions give compile errors, saying Required: Nothing, Found: Any.

When I change <out Any> to <Any>, the compile errors go away but now the function is unaccessible to anything that extends Any.

Is there a way of fixing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you need to take things out of the list *and* put things into the list, neither `in` or `out` works. The type argument needs to be invariant.

To make this work on all lists, you should add a generic parameter:

```
fun <T> MutableList<T>.reorder(a: Int, b: Int){
    val first = this[a]
    val second = this[b]
    this[a] = second
    this[b] = first
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
fun <T> MutableList<T>.reorder(a: Int, b: Int) {
    val first = this[a]
    val second = this[b]
    removeAt(a)
    add(a, second)
    removeAt(b)
    add(b, first)
}
```

**Update**

Sorry duplicate haven't seen the answer a minute before